# GLSL Reading From Sampler3d texture

Tags: opengl, glsl, textures, fragment-shader

I have 3D volume texture which I initialize it with below line :

```
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_RED, numX, numY, numZ, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, voldata);
```

In fragment shader, I want to read values of this texture but I cant read with `texture3d()` function.

below line give a compile error in fragment shader : (No matching Overloaded for texture3d)

```
float value = texture3d(VolumeTexture,vec3(0.2f,0.2f,0.2f);
```

How can I get the data from sampler3d?

OpenGLPart :

```
unsigned int texture;   
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, texture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_REPEAT);
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GL_RED, numX, numY, numZ, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, voldata);
free(voldata ); //free the texture
                ...
    display()
    {
                  ....
       glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);    
       int texture_location = glGetUniformLocation(shader.id(), "VolumeTexture");  
       glUniform1i(texture_location, 0);  
       glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D,volumetext);
                  ....
    }
```

My Fragment Shader :

```
    uniform sampler3D VolumeTexture;
    void main()
    {
        float value = 0;
                ...
        value = texture3d(VolumeTexture,vec3(0.2f,0.2f,0.2f);
                ...
    gl_FragColor = IntersectRay(ray);
    }
```

Note : My OpenGL version is 3.3

Comment: Is it OpenGL or OpenGL ES 2.0? If opengl then what version you target?
also post simplified version of your shader please.

Comment: @q______b: OpenGL ES 2.0 doesn't support 3D textures.

Comment: @NicolBolas there is an extension GL_OES_texture_3D for that on some devices.

Comment: "*Note : My OpenGL version is 3.5*" No, it is not. There is no OpenGL 3.5. There's an OpenGL **1**.5, but not 3.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I cant read with `texture3d()` function.

Try `texture3D()`.  Note the capital `D`.

Comment: pff I hate opengl...  thank you for your answer I have been looking for solution for hours :/

Comment: @CagkanToptas: That's not OpenGL. Most programming languages are case-sensitive. Best get used to it now.

Answer (score 6):

*Moving comment into a proper answer..*

Always (with no exceptions) do proper error checking when loading, compiling and linking your shaders. In the long run you will save a lot of time. This applies even if you verify your shader in an external program.

- After you call `glCompileShader(..)`, get the compile status by calling `glGetShaderiv(..)` with `GL_COMPILE_STATUS` as parameter.
- If the return value is 0, something went wrong
- Get the info log by querying for the length using `glGetShaderiv(..)` parameter `GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH`.
- Then fetch the log with `glGetShaderInfoLog`

This needs to be done each shader type (vertex, fragment, geo.. ).

In additon you should check link status after `glLinkProgram()` using `glGetProgramiv()` and `GL_LINK_STATUS` as parameter.

You would immediately seen an error like `0(19) : error C1008: undefined variable "texture3d"` not having to spend hours to track down the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try texture without 3D suffix, they deprecated functions with dimension specified in the OpenGL 4 and just overload texture function for different samplers. Also your line lacks one brace.